# use console and window form together in one application

Tags: c#, winforms, console

I want to use windows form and console application in same project and I can access the console like writeline() Readline() how using c#?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a windows form project and change the properties of the project > Application type  "Output type:" to Console application.  The program will load the form normally and console.write()'s will appear in the console app which will automagically display.